# Drupal Form module development

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7, form-api

I am developing a custom module by name 'form' in drupal 7.
I have placed my module folder in sites\all\modules\form.
And i have 2 files in 'form' folder. 'form.info' and 'form.module'.

'form.info'

```
name = Form
description = Form creation.
core = 7.x
```

And 'form.module' contains

```
<?php
function form_menu()
{
$items['form/examples'] = array
(
    'title' => 'Form API Examples',
    'description' => 'Examples of using the Form API',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_simple_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE
);
return $items;
}

function form_simple_form($form, &$form_submit)
{
$form['color'] = array
(
    '#title' => t('Favorite Color'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('What is the favorite color?'),
);
$form['submit'] = array
(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
)
return $form;
```

}

I am getting only blank white page when i click on the link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what link? Did you enable the module?

Comment: Title of the link displayed in home page...Yes... I have enabled the module

Comment: Try clearing the cache if u forgot...seriously there does not seem any problem in ur code except the semicolon u missed out  after `$form['submit']` mate

Comment: Thanks bro.. did semicolon and cache.. facing same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I works for me try this code for mymodule.module

```
 <?php
 // $Id$
    function form_menu()
    {
    $items['form/examples'] = array
    (
        'title' => 'Form API Examples',
        'description' => 'Examples of using the Form API',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('form_simple_form'),
        'access callback' => TRUE
    );
    return $items;
    }

    function form_simple_form($form, &$form_submit)
    {
    $form['color'] = array
    (
        '#title' => t('Favorite Color'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => t('What is the favorite color?'),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array
    (
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
    );
    return $form;
    }
```

When you create mymodule.info file

```
  name = Form
  description = Form creation.
  core = 7.x
  package = Form
```

Add package to it so you have your module in his own box. It is easier to find it betwen all of those modules.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your module to form1, as it is conflicting with Drupal internal form module, located in /includes.

You forgot a semicolon here:

```
$form['submit'] = array
(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
); //<- semicolon missing
```

Comment: @ArunBS Disable the old module, enable the new module.